# successfully called /getAssessmentRegistartion method from other microservice login but /getAssessmentRegistartion method fails to call other methods

Tags: java, microservices

my requirement is
Login Microservice-Employee microservice (or) Admin microservice based on the input
again Employee microservice implements two internal microservices those are registration for technical and behavioral assessment.
Admin can able to see all the list of Assessment registrations.
here we see my code I created two microservices Login and EmployeeAssesmentRegistration microservices.EmployeeAssessmentRegistration has /getAll,/getAssessmentRegistartion it is internally connected with /TechnicalAssessment,/BehavioralAssessment.Login microservice has /login method .I called /getAssessmentRegistration from login microservice but the two internal methods which are coonnected with /getAssessmentRegistration are failed why!
how can I able to call the the internal microservice of /getAssessmentsRegistartion from other microservice login.

login--->Emp-->technical and behavioral registartions(internal microservices)
|
Admin

I can able to call EmpAssessment registartion page after successfull login from login page then EmpAssessment registration page  is redirected to either technical or behavioural based on the selection  How can I able to achieve this, please help me.

Comment: please help me . I am using springboot.

Comment: please give me an idea how to achieve that